# Conditionally copy, paste, delete between worksheets data missing

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, copy-paste, worksheet

I have inherited a workbook that has suffered months of abuse (poor data entry, poor cut and paste, duplications, etc). I have nearly finished sorting the data but to prevent similar problems I am trying to automate some of the process. I am new to VBA and cannot figure out why my code isn't working. There are several worksheets that track an application through our new client process. Each worksheet has the same fifteen columns, metadata in the first 10 rows (=sum counts) and headers in the 11th row. When we receive interest in joining our organisation some simple data is entered into columns A-D and L-O inclusive. I want a particular row to move to the next worksheet when a date is entered to indicate a step in the process has been completed. For example when a client returns an application form, the date is entered into column G and the specific row is moved to the next worksheet and deleted from the original. The date entry works but columns L-O are not being copied. HELP!

The code I'm using is:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G12:G100" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    
        If IsDate(Target.Value) = True Then
        
            Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Target).Copy Sheets("Awaiting Interview").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Target.EntireRow.Delete
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Thank in advance.

AlVBA

Comment: Think about what range `Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Target)` represents.

Comment: Also note that `Range("G12:G100" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` should probably be `Range("G12:G" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`.

Comment: Thanks BigBen, I did have (G12:G) and cannot remember why I changed it. This change hasn't resolved the paste issue.

Comment: Right, because `Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Target)` only includes columns A to G.

Comment: @BigBen OIC, I did suspect that but I am not fluent enough in VBA to know how to change my code. i played with .entirerow without success. I want column G to be interrogated until a date is entered then the entire row cut and paste. Do you have a solution you could share?

Comment: If you want the entire row, then use `Me.Rows(Target.Row)`.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry I don't understand, can you show me where this fits in to my code please.

Comment: Replace `Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Target)` with `Me.Rows(Target.Row)`.

Comment: @BinBen, amazing mate, its works as I hoped. Thanks for taking the time to help me. Best regards Al